# Reshape data frame in R to wide format

Tags: r, aggregate, formula, reshape2

I am trying to convert a long format data frame to wide format using `dcast` of the `reshape2` package. My data frame looks something similar to the data frame below

```
X = c(3,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3)
Y = c(-3, -1, -3, -3, -1, -3, -3, -1, -3)
DATA = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 600, 200, 300)
measurement = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
DF <- data.frame(X, Y, DATA, measurement)
wideDF <- dcast(DF, X + Y ~ measurement, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var="DATA", drop = TRUE)
```

The `dcast` function works totally fine, but sometimes I have a huge list of column names that I don't want to hard code all the column names (in the above code like `X + Y`), I would like to pass the column names as a vector or however it makes my code simple. Can I achieve this using the `dcast` function or is there any function other than `dcast` to do so?

Comment: The `formula` parameter to `dcast()` has a special variable `....` which "_represents all other variables not used in the formula_" (`?reshape2::dcast`). This might by handy for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the formula as a string, and then use `as.formula()`

In `lhs` I'm grabbing all the column names that aren't `DATA` or `measurement` by using `setdiff()`.

```
library(reshape2)
lhs <- paste0(setdiff(names(DF), c("DATA", "measurement")), collapse = "+")

dcast(DF, as.formula(paste0(lhs, "~ measurement")), fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = "DATA", drop = TRUE)
#   X  Y   A   B   C
# 1 2 -1 200 100 200
# 2 3 -3 200 450 450
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly fine for me. Thanks